# Clojure closure

Tags: clojure

the other day I was trying to come up with an example of closure in Clojure. I came up with and example I had seen before and thought it was appropriate.

Alas, I was told it was not a good one and that I should provide something with let.

Can anyone shed some light?

```
(defn pow [x n] (apply * (repeat x n)))
(defn sq [y] (pow y 2))
(defn qb [y] (pow y 3))
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

A closure is a function that has access to some named value/variable outside its own scope, so from a higher scope surrounding the function when it was created (this excludes function arguments and local named values created within the function). Your examples do not qualify, because every function just uses named values from their own scopes.

Example:

```
(def foo 
  (let [counter (atom 0)]
    (fn [] (do (swap! counter inc) @counter))))

(foo) ;;=> 1
(foo) ;;=> 2
(foo) ;;=> 3, etc
```

Now `foo` is a function that returns the value of an atom that is outside its scope. Because the function still holds a reference to that atom, the atom will not be garbage-collected as long as `foo` is needed.

Answer (score 19):

Function that returns function i.e higher order functions are nice examples of closure.

```
(defn pow [n]
   (fn [x] (apply * (repeat n x))))

(def sq (pow 2))
(def qb (pow 3))
```

Comment: Hi, so my example would be a closure if I had defined the body of my pow like you did (the closure being the anon f)?

Comment: Yes, it would be one way to describe closure

Answer (score 5):

Another example of closure. There are two functions that share the same environment (`state`).

```
(defn create-object [init-state]
  (let [state (atom init-state)]
    {:getter (fn []
               @state)
     :setter (fn [new-val]
               (reset! state new-val))}))

(defn test-it []
  (let [{:keys [setter getter]} (create-object :init-value)]
    (println (getter))
    (setter :new-value)
    (println (getter))))

(test-it)
=> :init-value
   :new-value
```

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to have something that setup constant value(s) that are to be used each time.

```
(def myran 
  (let [constrand (rand)]
    (fn [n] (* n constrand))))


(myran 3)
2.7124521745892096
(myran 1)
0.9041507248630699
(myran 3)
2.7124521745892096
```

This will only set a value for "constrand" once.  This is a very contrived example, but I wanted to be able to do something like:

[image: JavaScript: The Good Parts]

This is from: [JavaScript: The Good Parts](https://youtu.be/hQVTIJBZook?t=1646)