# Numbering strings inside a vector in clojure

Tags: string, vector, clojure, count

Given the following string:

```
(def text "this is the first sentence . And this is the second sentence")
```

I wanted to count the number of times a word like "*this*" appears in the text, by appending the count after each occurrence of the word. Like this:

```
["this: 1", "is" "the" "first" "sentence" "." "and" "this: 2" ...]
```

As a first step, I tokenized the string:

```
 (def words (split text #" "))
```

Then I created a helper function to get the number of times "*this*" appears in the text:

```
 (defn count-this [x] (count(re-seq #"this" text)))
```

Finally I tried to use the result of the count-this function inside this loop:

```
(for [x words]
(if (= x "this")
(str "this: "(apply str (take (count-this)(iterate inc 0))))
x))
```

Here is what I get:

```
("this: 01" "is" "the" "first" "sentence" "." "And" "this: 01" "is" ...)
```

Comment: since no answer uses `clojure.core/frequencies` - here's the [doc](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/frequencies)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with that approach is that `(apply str (take (count-this)(iterate inc 0)))` is going to evaluate to the same thing every time.

To exert complete control over variables you generally want to use the loop form.

e.g.

```
(defn add-indexes [word phrase]
  (let [words (str/split phrase #"\s+")]
    (loop [src words
           dest []
           counter 1]
      (if (seq src)
        (if (= word (first src))
          (recur (rest src) (conj dest (str word " " counter)) (inc counter))
          (recur (rest src) (conj dest (first src)) counter))
        dest))))

user=> (add-indexes "this" "this is the first sentence . And this is the second sentence")
["this 1" "is" "the" "first" "sentence" "." "And" "this 2" "is" "the" "second" "sentence"]
```

`loop` allows you to specify the value of every of the loop variables on each pass. So you can decide to change them or not according to your own logic.

If you're willing to dip into Java and maybe do something that feels like cheating, this would work too.

```
(defn add-indexes2 [word phrase]
  (let [count (java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger. 1)]
    (map #(if (= word %) (str % " " (.getAndIncrement count)) %)
         (str/split phrase #"\s+"))))

user=> (add-indexes2 "this" "this is the first sentence . And this is the second sentence")
("this 1" "is" "the" "first" "sentence" "." "And" "this 2" "is" "the" "second" "sentence")
```

Using the mutable counter may not be pure, but on the other hand, it never escapes the context of the function, so its behavior cannot be changed by external forces.

Comment: No need for Java interop here, that's what Clojure uses `atom`s for.

Comment: @Bill Thanks for your answer . I chose your answer because that's where I am at now in learning Clojure (loops, recur).

Comment: Generally, I think loop is a good choice for something like this, because there's explicit support for managing values over iteration passes, and it's a bit more straightforward than trying to fit it into a reduce.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved fairly succinctly using [reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) to thread a counter through your vector traversal, in addition to building the new strings as needed:

```
(def text "this is the first sentence. And this is the second sentence.")

(defn notate-occurences [word string]
  (->
    (reduce 
        (fn [[count string'] member] 
            (if (= member word) 
              (let [count' (inc count)]
                [count' (conj string' (str member ": " count'))])
              [count (conj string' member)]))
          [0 []]
          (clojure.string/split string #" "))
    second))

(notate-occurences "this" text) 
;; ["this: 1" "is" "the" "first" "sentence." "And" "this: 2" "is" "the" "second""sentence."]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to keep some state as you are going along. `reduce`, `loop`/`recur` and `iterate` all do this. `iterate` just transitions from one state to another. Here is the transition function:

```
(defn transition [word]
  (fn [[[head & tail] counted out]]
    (let [[next-counted to-append] (if (= word head)
                                    [(inc counted) (str head ": " (inc counted))]
                                    [counted head])]
      [tail next-counted (conj out to-append)])))
```

Then you can use `iterate` to exercise this function until there is no input left:

```
(let [in (s/split "this is the first sentence . And this is the second sentence" #" ")
      step (transition "this")]
    (->> (iterate step [in 0 []])
         (drop-while (fn [[[head & _] _ _]]
                       head))
         (map #(nth % 2))
         first))

;; => ["this: 1" "is" "the" "first" "sentence" "." "And" "this: 2" "is" "the" "second" "sentence"]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defn split-by-word [word text]
    (remove empty?
        (flatten
            (map #(if (number? %) (str word ": " (+ 1 %)) (clojure.string/split (clojure.string/trim %) #" "))
                 (butlast (interleave
                      (clojure.string/split (str text " ") (java.util.regex.Pattern/compile (str "\\b" word "\\b")))
                      (range)))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you can find a simple way of composing your solution from existing Clojure functions in a very succinct way.

Here's two quite short solutions to your problem. First, if you don't need the result as a sequence, but replacements to the string are ok:

```
(require '(clojure.string))

(def text "this is the first sentence . And this is the second sentence")

(defn replace-token [ca token]
  (swap! ca inc)
  (str token ": " @ca))

(defn count-this [text]
  (let [counter     (atom 0)
        replacer-fn (partial replace-token counter)]
    (clojure.string/replace text #"this" replacer-fn)))

(count-this text)
; => "this: 1 is the first sentence . And this: 2 is the second sentence"
```

The above solution makes use of the fact that a function can be supplied to `clojure.string/replace`.

Second, if you need the result as a sequence, there is some overhead from tokenizing:

```
(defn count-seq [text]
  (let [counter      (atom 0)
        replacer-fn  (partial replace-token counter)
        converter    (fn [tokens] (map #(if (not= % "this")
                                            % 
                                            (replacer-fn %))
                                       tokens))]
    (-> text
        (clojure.string/split #" ")
        (converter))))

(count-seq text)

; => ("this: 1" "is" "the" "first" "sentence" "." "And" "this: 2" "is" "the" "second" "sentence")
```

The `loop-recur` pattern is very common for beginning Clojurians, who come from non-functional languages. In most cases, there is a cleaner and more idiomatic solution using functional processing with `map`, `reduce`, and friends.

Like other answers have stated, the main issue in your original attempt is the binding of your counter. In fact, `(iterate inc 0)` is not bound to anything. Look at my examples above to think through the scope of the bound atom `counter`. As a reference, [here is an example of using closures](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14875147/8123584), which could also be used in this case with great success!

As a footnote for above examples: For cleaner code, you should make a more general solution by extracting and reusing the common parts of `count-seq` and `count-this` functions. Also, the local `converter` function could be extracted out of `count-seq`. `replace-token` is already general for all tokens, but consider how the whole solution could be expanded beyond matching text other than "this". These are left as exercises for the reader.